# What is the correlation between Page Fault and I/O?

Tags: io, operating-system, kernel, page-fault, page-caching

I'm taking a course on OS in the Linux Kernel and it's written in my course and here's what's written in it:

```
Big Page Cache is causing more Page Faults and thus less I/O. 
Small Page Cache is causing less Page Faults and thus more I/O.
```

Why is that true ? What is the link between Page Fault and I/O ?

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed these correctly?  "is providing" isn't typically used this way.

Comment: You're right, it was a bad translation. "causing" is maybe more accurate.